# Optimal Graph Splitting

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-optimization

**Question:**
Given a finite symmetric TSP instance with $2n$ sites, what is the complexity of and what are algorithms for determining two sets of sites $A$ and $B$, each containing $n$ elemenents so that

- the difference the weight sums of edges in $A$ and of edges in $B$ is minimal
- the weight sum of edges connecting a site in $A$ with a site in $B$ is minimal?

Answer (score 2):

Both of these problems share many similarities with the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) for which there exists efficient greedy algorithms, dynamic programming approaches, and exact methods (see link).

Comment: As the partition problem doesn't have to deal with interdependence between the individual numbers, it apparently provides a lower bound for the complexity of "graph partitioning" problem. I currently don't see how to transform the graph partitioning problem to the "set partitioning" problem to make the existing algorithms directly applicable.